# Vue.js Set value in computed properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, computed-properties

I have 3 inputs like this:

```
<input type="text" v-model="settings['apple']" />
<input type="text" v-model="settings['banana']" />
<input type="text" v-model="settings['orange']" />
```

When a user enter value for a input I want to get the value which user entered to process value and update new value. I am using computed properties to process value:

```
data() {
            return {
                settings: {}

            }
        },

    computed: {
            settings: {
                set: function (newValue) {
                    var parts = newValue.match(/[\s\S]{1,2}/g) || [];

           // Set new value ...
                }
            }
        },
```

The problem is how can I know which input user entered and set the new value?

Comment: What does your getter look like?

Comment: @nils I don't have getter function.

Comment: How are you using `v-model="settings['apple']"` then? Are you mixing `$data` properties with a `setter`?

Comment: @nils I just update my $data properties above. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Attributes defined in `data` and `computed` should be mutually exclusive - defining the same attribute in both places is asking for trouble. Also, objects under data should have default values.

So, instead, have your computed return a different object which is all of the transformed values. Leave the settings that your inputs are bound to with `v-model` alone. Then you can bind separately to the computed object and display it to your user if you like.

```
data() {
        return {
            settings: {
                "apple": "",
                "banana": "",
                "orange": ""
            }
        }
    },

computed: {
        transformed_settings: function () {
            /* create and return an object with transformed apple, banana, orange */
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to declare apple, banana and Orange as data elements or variables. Define functions based on a user input under methods (Not computed) then use @change="CheckUserInput" property in the inputboxes